# Python3 - 'ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm programming in Python 3 and OpenCV on a Jupyter Notebook on Windows.
I'm following this tutorial: http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html

But i get this error:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

From:

> ---> 15     addrs, labels = zip(*c)

This code should list my images and label them, but it won't work. Here's the code:

````
from random import shuffle
import glob
shuffle_data = True  # shuffle the addresses before saving
hdf5_path = 'my path/PetImages/dataset.hdf5'  # address to where you want to save the hdf5 file
cat_dog_train_path = 'my path/PetImages/Train/*.jpg'
addrs = glob.glob(cat_dog_train_path)
labels = [0 if 'cat' in addr else 1 for addr in addrs]  # 0 = Cat, 1 = Dog
# to shuffle data
if shuffle_data:
    c = list(zip(addrs, labels))
    shuffle(c)
    addrs, labels = zip(*c)

# Divide the hata into 60% train, 20% validation, and 20% test
train_addrs = addrs[0:int(0.6*len(addrs))]
train_labels = labels[0:int(0.6*len(labels))]
val_addrs = addrs[int(0.6*len(addrs)):int(0.8*len(addrs))]
val_labels = labels[int(0.6*len(addrs)):int(0.8*len(addrs))]
test_addrs = addrs[int(0.8*len(addrs)):]
test_labels = labels[int(0.8*len(labels)):]```
````

Comment: That suggests that `c` is empty. Double check your data.

Comment: My guess would be that the path to you image folder is wrong and therefore `addrs` is empty.

Comment: Well, inside my `Train` folder there's 2 folders: `Cat` and `Dog` and inside them there are lots of images, and i've checked again, just to be sure.

Comment: Right, your images are in `.../Train/Cat` and `.../Train/Dog` but the path you set in your script is `.../Train`, which doesn't contain any `*.jpg` files. If you want all jpegs from all sub-directories, the correct path to set in your script would be `cat_dog_train_path = 'my path/PetImages/Train/*/*.jpg'`

Comment: That was it! Thank you.